# I have read Database name WAJ_Project_Management.but i have an error in that table .error call ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE Estimation_Employee(
    emp_id VARCHAR (20),
    est_id VARCHAR (20),
    PRIMARY KEY (emp_id,est_id),
    constraint foreign key(est_id) references Estimaton(est_id)
    on delete cascade on update cascade,
    constraint foreign key(emp_id) references Employee(emp_id)
    on delete cascade on update cascade
)engine = innodb;
```

Comment: Resolving FK issues of this sort require sight of the referenced tables.

Comment: Make sure that both tables are using the same engine. And post the structure of the Estimation and Employee